# Interpolating 2D data on a hemisphere in order to have $C^2$ function but no overshoot

Tags: scipy, interpolation

I am interpolating a 2D dataset on a hemisphere, and I am currently using `scipy.Rbf` that I like for its simplicity.

I am defining the norm of the interpolator with the haversine formula in order to respect the fact that I am on a hemisphere, and doing a cubic interpolation in order to have a $C^2$ function at the end, but the problem is that I also want to avoid overshoot, meaning that no interpolated point can be higher than the maximum known value or lower than the minimum known value (more precisely, it can be lower than the minimum known value but always greater than zero, but the first requirement would be enough).

The best solution would be to have directly a function that I can give to `scipy.Rbf` that can handle these conditions, but if it's not possible, I may try a different algorithm.

Comment: What do you mean for overshoot?

Comment: No interpolated value can be higher than the maximum known value or lower than the minimum known value.

Comment: It sounds as if you don't need an interpolator but an approximating function, am I understanding it right?

Comment: Not exactly. Let's say that I have a set of points $\{\{0, 0\}, \{\pi/4, 0\}, \{\pi/4, \pi/2\}, \{\pi/4, \pi\}, \{\pi/4, 3\pi/2\}, ...\}$ where the first value in each duet is the $\theta$ coordinate and the second is the $\phi$ coordinate, and for each point I know its value $\{5000, 2000, ...\}$. I may now want to know what will be the values for new points $\{\{\pi/4, \pi/3\}, ...\}$. I want to do an interpolation on these points, that will always give me positive values less than the maximum known value, and that will create a set of points that is $C^2$.

Answer (score 1):

You may have a look at Monoton Preserving Cubic $C^1$ or Quintic Hermite $C^2$ interpolants, [here](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1989-52-186/S0025-5718-1989-0962209-1/).
A 1D version is available via **pchip method** in Matlab, [here](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pchip.html).
See also the 2D **makima variant** [here](https://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2019/04/29/makima-piecewise-cubic-interpolation/) (not fully monoton). An extension to sphere surfaces may require some effort, however still feasible.

Comment: Hermite interpolants are not $C^1$ for 2-manifolds, in general. They might have continuous partial derivatives, that is a necessary but not sufficient condition.

Comment: @nicoguaro Sure, possible for partial derivatives in N-D only. The answer should perhaps rather be understood as a hint.